# IcCube Excel Xmla opens one session (connection) per PivotTable

Tags: excel, connection-string, iccube, xmla

We have produced some Excel files using Xmla Pivot Tables against Iccube schemas.

Everything is working well except the fact that we noticed :

Each Pivot Table on a single file (even single worksheet tab) triggers a connection to the server.
Thus, when opening (and refreshing) a file with 5 Pivot tables, we are asked 5 times to enter credentials for the same connection.

Is there a way to avoid that ? (Of course, for security reasons, we cannot store the password in the connection string, just would like to register one time per connection needed)

I have to produce an excel file with more than 100 Pivots and cannot imagine entering 100 times a password when opening it.

As you can see on following picture, I have 3 opened sessions : 1 (green) for html session and 2 (red) because I opened an excel file with 2 Pivot Tables.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with a single connection shared by all the pivot table this seems to be the default behavior of Excel. One possible solution would be to write a macro to request the user credentials and somehow edit the connection on the fly with this information.

Hope that helps.